# Symfony 4.1 + Propel + Model Issue

Tags: symfony, model, propel

I have upgrade Symfony 3.4 ( Propel ORM ) to Symfony 4.1 (Propel ORM).

I have added my schema.xml file in scr->propel folder

```
.

<database name="yoursource" defaultIdMethod="native" namespace="Entity"> 
<table name="activity_log" idMethod="native" phpName="ActivityLog">
    <column name="activity_log_id" phpName="ActivityLogId" type="INTEGER" primaryKey="true" autoIncrement="true" required="true"/>
    <column name="activity_type_id" phpName="ActivityTypeId" type="INTEGER" required="true" defaultValue="1"/>
</table>
</database>
```

My Model generate in src->Entity folder

My Controller code like below

```
namespace App\Controller;
use Entity;
use Entity\Person; 
class PersonController extends AbstractController 
{    
   public function logincheckAction(Request $request) {
        $person = PersonQuery::create()->filterByEmail($email)->findOne();
    }
}
```

**Get below error :**
Attempted to load class "PersonQuery" from namespace "App\Controller".
Did you forget a "use" statement for another namespace?

Thanks for help..

Comment: what happens when you add `use [pathTo\]PersonQuery;` to your usage section?

Comment: how is your schema.xml related to this?